# Are JavaScript equality operators for DOM elements cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, equality, dom

Will `==` and `===` work correctly in all browsers for DOM elements?  If the code gets a reference to a raw DOM element in two different ways, will they be both `==` and `===` equal in all browsers?

Comment: @AndyRay, why would I close it?  If you want to answer it go ahead.  It's better if you have references.

Comment: @AndyRay, no, you didn't.  Apparently you're not familiar with the difference between a comment and answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It has worked for me at least when comparing element from event object to element reference stored to variable.

Comment: I had a look at the specification... all it says is that the operators return `true` if `x` and `y` are the same object. But this does not imply that various DOM methods must return references to the same DOM node so that they can be considered equal in JS. I didn't find anything in this regard in the DOM spec either.

Comment: @Andy: No, it's asking whether the same *host object* and specifically DOM objects retrieved via different methods are equal in every browser.

Comment: I think it's just confusion on the OP's part. A DOM node is an object in memory, like all javascript objects. The DOM API is a fun mess but at least that part is sane. If they didn't === each other then all of javascript would fall apart. Maybe a better way of putting it is `var a = {}; var b = a; var c = { q: a }; c.q === b // ?`

Comment: @AndyRay, the question boils down to whether getting the node via different routes results in the *same* object in memory.

Comment: @Andy: The problem is that the DOM API defines only interfaces, and all these implementation-specific memory aspects. If there only was a sentence saying like "DOM nodes must pass equality tests in the host language", all would be fine. But I haven't found anything like this so far...

Answer (score 5):

> Will == and === work correctly in all browsers for DOM elements?

Yes, those equality operators will work as defined by the ECMAScript standard.

One word of caution, `==` often does things that developers do not expect, such as casting to a string when compared to a string value. This would make the following statement true, although it might not be the desired result:

```
document.createElement('div') == '[object HTMLDivElement]'
```

In most cases, you'll want to use the `===` operator.

Comment: As Felix indicated, the ECMAScript standard does not really say anything about the DOM.